# File Revision List File Names?

Tags: google-drive-api

Can I retrieve the file names of a file's revision history? I'm using the [Revisions call from the api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions#resource) and was hoping the originalFilename would be populated but it isn't for each file. Is it possible to get the filename of each revision in the history tree?

*edit* Here is some more information on the problem. When we upload a new revision, the title/filename of the document almost always changes. We use this title/filename for multiple reasons. However on 08-12-2014, any new updates to a document would result in the originalFilename (from the [Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions#resource) call from the api) being blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the history of file names is not tracked.  You can only get the most recent file name.

Any information you want to retrieve from the revision history should be encoded in the contents of the file.